# How to implement multiprocessing (or other solution) in this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

Need help with multiprocessing!

So, I've been building my code here that converts xlsx to csv and puts it into a temporary folder, then appends those files into a list which will be concatenated and (in the future) sent to a database. For now, this is the code I have working:

```
from pathlib import Path
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
import time
from pathlib import Path
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil

start_time = round(time.time(), 2)

root_path = Path("C:/Teste")
files = Path(root_path).glob('*')

print("Creating a temporary folder...")
CSVFolder = "{}\\TempCSV".format(files)
CSVFolderLoc = glob.glob(CSVFolder)


directory = "TempCSV"
JoinTempPath = os.path.join(root_path, directory)

#Foldercreation gives an error if exists, so this code checks if it exists and deletes it
if os.path.isdir(JoinTempPath) == True:
    print("--Removing existent Temporary CSV Directory--")
    shutil.rmtree(JoinTempPath)

# Create the directory 'TempCSV' in 'parent_dir'
os.mkdir(JoinTempPath)
print("Directory '% s' created" % directory)




def func():
    list = []
    for file in files:
        if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx':
            print("Now converting '% s' file" % file)
            #if it finds xlsx files, converts it to csv in the temporary folder
            destFile = os.path.join(JoinTempPath, "{}.csv".format(file.stem))
            print(destFile)
            Xlsx2csv(file, outputencoding="utf-8").convert(destFile)
            
            #appends those converted files into the empty list
            for csvFile in destFile:
                print(round(time.time() - start_time,2))
                list.append(pd.read_csv(destFile, dtype='unicode'))
                print(round(time.time() - start_time,2))
       
    #concatenates (will be send to a database in the next version)
    x = pd.concat(list)
    print(round(time.time() - start_time,2))

#execute the function
func()
```

I need your help to improve the speed. I have been trying to implement Multiprocessing but I have failed. I've tried something like this but I saw nothing different happening:

```
import multiprocessing

(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    p1 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= func)
    p2 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= func)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Can you please help me implement multiprocessing or other solution for this loop to run in parallel?

I've also tried this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    processes=[]
    num_processes= os.cpu_count() #nr of cpus to distribute workload
    
    #create processes and assign a function for each process
    for i in range(0, num_processes):
        process = Process(target=func)
        processes.append(Process)

    #start all processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
        

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

But got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\CatarinaRibeiro\Desktop\DatabaseConfig\Main2.py", line 130, in <module>
    process.start()
TypeError: BaseProcess.start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Which part of your process do you want to run *in parallel*? Is your bottleneck cpu related or I/O related? You will likely need to restructure your process to separate the parts that need concurrency. I like the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module its *interface* makes things simple.

Comment: Keep in mind that it takes time to *spin-up* separate processes and if you need to pass data between processes that also takes time.

Comment: I'd like to run in parallel the conversion of files part

Comment: And the bottleneck is more I/O related

Comment: How about using ProcessPoolExecutor then use its *map* functionality to pass a list of files to be processed?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the way you do it, both of the processes convert all the files.
To get faster, you will need to split the file list between the different thread and then run each thread with only a part of the files.

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil

start_time = round(time.time(), 2)

root_path = Path("C:/Teste")
files = Path(root_path).glob('*')

print("Creating a temporary folder...")
CSVFolder = "{}\\TempCSV".format(files)
CSVFolderLoc = glob.glob(CSVFolder)


directory = "TempCSV"
JoinTempPath = os.path.join(root_path, directory)

#Foldercreation gives an error if exists, so this code checks if it exists and deletes it
if os.path.isdir(JoinTempPath) == True:
    print("--Removing existent Temporary CSV Directory--")
    shutil.rmtree(JoinTempPath)

# Create the directory 'TempCSV' in 'parent_dir'
os.mkdir(JoinTempPath)
print("Directory '% s' created" % directory)




def func(files_list):
    list = []
    for file in files_list:
        if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx':
            print("Now converting '% s' file" % file)
            #if it finds xlsx files, converts it to csv in the temporary folder
            destFile = os.path.join(JoinTempPath, "{}.csv".format(file.stem))
            print(destFile)
            Xlsx2csv(file, outputencoding="utf-8").convert(destFile)
            
            #appends those converted files into the empty list
            for csvFile in destFile:
                print(round(time.time() - start_time,2))
                list.append(pd.read_csv(destFile, dtype='unicode'))
                print(round(time.time() - start_time,2))
       
    #concatenates (will be send to a database in the next version)
    x = pd.concat(list)
    print(round(time.time() - start_time,2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = list(files)  
    p1 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= func, args=(files[:len(files)//2],))
    p2 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= func, args=(files[len(files)//2:],))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Will this be faster than a *non-concurrent* solution?

Comment: It should be, since instead of converting let's say 10 files the ones after the others you will do that twice on 5 files but simultaneously.

Comment: When I tried this, it gave me an error. Can you help @wwii?

 File "c:\Users\CatarinaRibeiro\Desktop\from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv.py", line 56, in <module>
    p1 =  multiprocessing.Process(target= func, args=(files[:len(files)//2],))
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it when writing the answer, this error mean that the `files` variable is a generator rather than a list. If you cast it as a list before starting the thread, it should be alright.  (the answer has been updated)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're spawning two processes which both do the same thing, so it'll either be the same or slower (due to file contention). You need the processes to split the work. An obvious choice here would be to split the list of files N-ways and have each process do 1/Nth of the work. Finding the files and the final concatenation should happen in the main process for simplicity's sake.

I think a good way to use multiprocessing (or multithreading) in python is with the concurrent futures module, which simplifies things. Here's a really simple example with similar structure to your code:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor
import glob
import time

def process_file(file):
    # Some long-running processing...
    time.sleep(0.5)
    # Done!
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Find some files
    files = glob.glob('*.txt')
    print(f'Running process_file on {files}')

    # Run process_file in parallel for each file in files, using as many cores as possible.
    results = Executor().map(process_file, files)
    
    # Concatenate
    final_result = '\n'.join(results)
    print(final_result)
```

You'd basically move the body of your `for file in files` loop to a function like `process_file` above, and do a `list = Executor().map(process_file, files)` call instead of explicitly looping.